# HA setup of Spark Cluster using Zookeeper Quorum

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zookeeper, high-availability, apache-curator

We are trying to setup Spark HA setup with ZK.
We have 2 machines for Master for Spark process and another 3 for Spark Slaves 
The configuration In Master Machine for spark HA done as below in spark-env.sh :

```
 # - SPARK_DAEMON_JAVA_OPTS, to set config properties for all daemons (e.g. "-Dx=y")

    export SPARK_DAEMON_JAVA_OPTS="-Dspark.deploy.recoveryMode=ZOOKEEPER -Dspark.deploy.zookeeper.url=DEV-SMP-Manager01:2181DEV-SMP-Worker01:2181,DEV-SMP-Worker05:2181"
```

where DEV-SMP-Manager01:2181DEV-SMP-Worker01:2181,DEV-SMP-Worker05:2181 are ZK Quorum. and they are up and running .

When we start the master(s) using command sbin/start-master.sh  ,

We have seen some error messages related to curator

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/curator/RetryPolicy at storm.kafka.KafkaSpout.open(KafkaSpout.java:85) at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__3373$fn__3388.invoke(executor.clj:522) at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__464.invoke(util.clj:461) at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.curator.RetryPolicy at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372) at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ... 5 more

Version used :-
Spark - spark-1.6.1 
ZK - 3.4.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try adding the curator-client jar in classpath by adding the following in your spark-env.sh file :

```
SPARK_CLASSPATH="$SPARK_CLASSPATH:/path/to/curator-client.jar"
```

Comment: Yes Rakesh , after I posted it , i added the same downloaded the jars and then problem resolved . Thanks .

Comment: Please accept the answer so that others in the forum can benefit out of it using the tick mark below my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Rakesh , Please can you see my new issue ... related to same as headline ...so I edited the description ... any idea ?

Comment: Suman, please change the description to older and create a new question. The stackoverflow moderators may have objection on this.

Comment: Also, your question will not be seen by others as an answer is already accepted.